# Hide/show all DIV but the one picked

Tags: jquery, html

See I have this HTML code:

```
<form method="post" id="product_create" action="">
    <ul>
        <li id="tab1"><a href="#">Step 1</a></li>
        <li id="tab2"><a href="#">Step 2</a></li>
        <li id="tab3"><a href="#">Step 3</a></li>
        <li id="tab4"><a href="#">Step 4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="categories-picker"></div>
    <div style="display:none" id="product-select"></div>
    <div style="display:none" id="product-details"></div>
    <div style="display:none" id="product-stock"></div>
</form>
```

I need to show/hide all `div` others than picked one. In this case if I click in `li#tab1` then `div#categories-picker` should show and others should hide no matter where I was meaning for example if I was in `div#product-stock`. The same behavior should go to the rest. I made this code:

```
$("#product_create").on("click", "tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4", function() {
    $('#product_create').not($(this)).hide();
});
```

Any advice on this? Maybe is a better way to do this but I don't find it

Comment: Can you not give the `li`s a class?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP yes I can, I'm thinking also in add a `data-*` attribute and then write the same name as DIVs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build some kind of relation between the `<li>`s and `<div>`s you need displayed on clicking those `<li>`s. Below i've added a `data` attribute, `display` to each `<li>` to indicate the `<div>` to be displayed on clicking each.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wyh5y/)**

```
<form method="post" id="product_create" action="">
    <ul>
        <li id="tab1" data-display="categories-picker"><a href="#">Step 1</a></li>
        <li id="tab2" data-display="product-select"><a href="#">Step 2</a></li>
        <li id="tab3" data-display="product-details"><a href="#">Step 3</a></li>
        <li id="tab4" data-display="product-stock"><a href="#">Step 4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="categories-picker"></div>
    <div style="display:none" id="product-select"></div>
    <div style="display:none" id="product-details"></div>
    <div style="display:none" id="product-stock"></div>
</form>
```

And then use that *relation* to show the appropriate `<div>`

```
$("#product_create").on("click", "#tab1, #tab2, #tab3, #tab4", function() {
    $('#'+$(this).data('display')).show().siblings('div').hide();
    return false;
});
```

---

**Update:**

Changing to a DIV only if it isn't empty

```
$("#product_create").on("click", "#tab1, #tab2, #tab3, #tab4", function() {
    var div = $('#'+$(this).data('display'));
    if($.trim(div.html()) !== '') {
        $('#'+$(this).data('display')).show().siblings('div').hide();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: excelent, I just need to ask for one thing how I check if DIV has content, if has then show as your does in your code if not remain in the actual DIV?

Comment: @Reynier - Yes, you can do that as well. Check the update in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `li` child - it should be:

```
$("#product_create").on("click", "#tab1, #tab2, #tab3, #tab4", function() {
    $('#product_create li').not($(this)).hide();
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EJpaW/

Answer (score 0):

Give them a class of `.tab` and use this:

```
$("#product_create").on("click",".tab",function() {
   $("#product_create .tab").not($(this)).hide(); 
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmokeyPHP/AkHEN/)